# How to ensure URL remains restful on submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

When I navigate to my rails application below

http://myurl.co.za/tags/new

I want to create a new tag. I click save and validation kicks in and asks me to insert a tag name, but my url changes to

http://myurl.co.za/tags

Even though in my create action in my tags controller I am saying

```
render :new
```

Why?
Is there a way to make sure it will always be /new

---

Note I simplified the example. The actual scenario is a little more complicated. Please see code below.

myurl.co.za/courses/[my-course-name]/course_registrations/new

changes to

myurl.co.za/courses/[my-course-name]/course_registrations

```
class CourseRegistrationsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :set_to_use_course_registration_partials

  def new
    @course = Course.includes(:partner).friendly.find(params[:course_id])
    redirect_to courses_path if !@course.is_published && !current_user.try(:is_admin?)
    @course_registration = CourseRegistration.new
    gon.perform_frontend_validation = 'false'
  end

  def create
    @course = Course.includes(:partner).friendly.find(params[:course_id])
    @course_registration = CourseRegistration.new(course_registration_params) 
    @course_registration.course_id = @course.id
    @course_registration.presentation = @course.presentation 

    if @course_registration.save
      @course_registration.subscribe_to_newsletter
      flash[:success] = "Registration Successful"
      redirect_to action: "success"
    else
      gon.perform_frontend_validation = 'true'
      flash.now[:error] = "Please ensure all fields have been filled in"
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end

  def success
    @course = Course.includes(:partner).friendly.find(params[:course_id])
  end


private

  # ensures correct navigation and flash rendered in application layout
  def set_to_use_course_registration_partials
    @use_course_registration_partials = true
  end

  def course_registration_params
    params.require(:course_registration).permit(:first_name, 
                                                :last_name, 
                                                :email, 
                                                :telephone,
                                                :identity_number,
                                                :date_of_birth,
                                                :address_street_1,
                                                :address_street_2,
                                                :address_city,
                                                :address_state,
                                                :address_postal_code,
                                                :address_country,
                                                :billing_address_street_1,
                                                :billing_address_street_2,
                                                :billing_address_city,
                                                :billing_address_state,
                                                :billing_address_postal_code,
                                                :billing_address_country,
                                                :is_billing_same_as_physical_address,
                                                :payment_scheme,
                                                :payment_method,
                                                :promo_code,
                                                :require_tax_invoice,
                                                :tax_invoice_company_name,
                                                :tax_invoice_vat_number,
                                                :crm_reg_id,
                                                :receive_newsletter,
                                                :terms_and_conditions)
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post your full `create action` of your controller?

Comment: render 'new' will still render the new template at the current path, which is http://myurl.co.za/tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs because when you submit a form from a new action, you are POSTing to http://myurl.co.za/tags and not http://myurl.co.za/tags/new. The form that is then appearing is in response to that POST action, so it appears at the appropriate URL. So the behaviour is Restful, as it has a unique combination of uri and HTTP action.

You could alter the behaviour of your app so that create handles POSTs to http://myurl.co.za/tags/new. That would also be restful and you can do it by modifying your routes:

```
resources :tags do
  collection do
    post 'new', action: :create, as: :create_tag
  end
end
```

You'll then need to ensure that the form rendered in your new view, specifies the path create_tag_path as its destination url.

Finally I would emphasis, both this and the standard Rails behaviour are Restful. They are just different implementations of Restful.

Comment: There is probably a better way of specifying the route. This is just the one that came to my mind first. It would perhaps be better to alter the behaviour of the route that leads to tags#create, as to be fully Restful I think the routes need to be unique. With the example shown there are now two routes that lead to tags#create.